# How does you Reconstruct SVN repository from working copy without losing svn history

Tags: eclipse, svn

My service provider changed URLs on SVN repository. We were unable to reconnect from Eclipse SVN plug-in.
Based on their suggestion, tried Share Project, which allowed us to redirect to new URL, but ended up screwing
up repository files.

Still have intact local copies with SVN state on a client machine.
Is there a way to build a new SVN repository and load in local working copy WITH SCN HISTORY intact.
When we did this with Eclipse plug-in Team prompts, it ending up recreating projects but lost the
original SVN change history, which we would like to preserve.

Thanks

Comment: All that changed is the URL of the SVN repository?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the short answer is "no".

An SVN checkout does not donwload the complete history to your workstation. It just downloads the current state. When you make changes, it remembers what it downloaded so that it can compare what it downloaded to what you have now. So you could reconstruct "last revision" and "updates since last revision". That's about it.

Eclipse keeps track of edits, but I don't think it's going to remember edits across checkouts, because that's going to look like a new file. It has a finite buffer anyway.

If you were so fortunate that you have a directory where you checked out revision 1, and then you kept that and checked out revision 2 to another directory, etc, you could reconstruct the history. But few people do that because it would normally be pointless because the history is in SVN.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get history from Working Copy, because WC is always only slice of repository

If SP inly changed URL and you can and know how to work with pure CLI SVN and WC as directory in FS - you can

- switch or relocate working copy

or

- checkout from new URL new project